# How to manage session on a load balancing architecture in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

My project is moving from a single server architecture to multiserver architecture with aws load balancing.
In single-server architecture, I had used store.js for session management. But store is not working in new architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sticky sessions to force the clients to keep connecting to the same instance. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html